# How does PouchDB decide whether to use GET or POST for a view?

Tags: pouchdb

PouchDB's map/reduce query API can send very long GET parameters to CouchDB, or it can POST. PouchDB seems to do one or the other depending. How does it decide, and can the method be chosen with a parameter? https://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_database

Answer (score 0):

PouchDB considers using POST when the `opts.keys` option is not undefined when using a map/reduce view, but it also checks that the GET url is not too long. Unfortunately PouchDB's `MAX_URL_LENGTH`, picked using stackoverflow.com, is longer than the CouchDB 2.3 maximum length. For that reason queries with a medium number of keys will use GET and fail. There is not an option to force one method or another.

https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/blob/master/packages/node_modules/pouchdb-abstract-mapreduce/src/index.js#L265

(It looks like PouchDB has different rules for when to use POST for other CouchDB APIs)

The longest GET request I can send to my CouchDB 2.3 is 1335 bytes or 1300 bytes without the protocol, host, and port.

It turns out this was a regression in CouchDB 2.3 and should be fixed in CouchDB 2.3.1. https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1810